# Regex 4 capture groups

Tags: javascript, regex

In JS, I have some strings which need to break down into capture groups. The problem is there are some variations.

**String variations:**

```
              group3::group4
       group2:group3::group4
       group1|group3::group4
group1|group2:group3::group4
```

So far I've able to build the below regex pattern. Which captures when all groups are there. But I wasn't able to capture each group when one or more groups are missing. Can anyone help me with this to figure it out? (Every time each group must be captured by the relevant capture group)

```
\([^\r\n]+)?\|([^\r\n]+)?:([^\r\n]+)?::([^\r\n]+)?\g
```

This runs for each string in a loop. So the final result should looks like this for each string.

```
array(01 => "group1", 02 => null, 03 => "group3", 04 => "group4")
```

Thanks in advance.

--[ANSWER]--

With the help of @tshiono, I coded the following example, Posting here in case if anyone needed it.

```js
// const text = 'group3::group4';
// const text = 'group2:group3::group4';
// const text = 'group1|group3::group4';
const text = 'group1|group2:group3::group4';

const regex = /(?:([^:|\s]*)\|)?(?:([^:|\s]*):)?([^:|\s]*)::([^:|\s]*)/;
const match = text.match(regex);

console.log( match );
```

Comment: Can you show us what the desired result would be please, also the code you wrote would help in producing a good answer, is it JS or PHP

Comment: Each text (for example text "group4" must go to the capture group 4). This is run by a loop (array) so one line at a time.

Comment: So the final result should looks like this ```array(01 => "group1", 02 => null, 03 => "group3", 04 => "group4")```.

Comment: If you put that into the QUESTION, then people can see it

Comment: @stackminu Would [this](https://regex101.com/r/HBwRKp/1/) help?

Comment: Sure. I just put it into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
/(?:([^:|\s]*)\|)?(?:([^:|\s]*):)?([^:|\s]*)::([^:|\s]*)/gm
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GocBWF/1)

Comment: Hey, Really appreciate your help on the above pattern. Anyway, my requirement got a little bit advanced, and now I'm clueless about how to match, I'm pretty sure you can help me with this as well. Will you be able to take a look: https://regex101.com/r/yL7gZ9/1